# Passing WS connection down to children via props React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, ratchet

I'm using Ratchet on a backend PHP server to run my websocket and I'm using React as the front end.

I have my socket open and I can connect via JS without an issue.

The problem I am having is that I can't seem to pass the websocket connection down to any child components.

For example, I have a chat component with 3 sub components :

`Main` (the wrapper for the whole thing), `Closed` (closed state of the pop up chat box), `Open` (displays all messages etc) and `Input` (the form input section that handles new messages).

The most logical place to init the websocket is in the `Main` component so I do that and then pass the connection down to the `Open` child component :

```
componentDidMount() {
  this._isMounted = true;
  this.openWebsocket();
}

openWebsocket = () => {
  this.conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
  this.conn.onopen = () => {
    console.log('Connected!');
  };

  this.conn.onmessage = e => {
    console.log(e.data);
  };
};

......

<Open
   conn={this.conn}
/>
```

And then in `Open` I pass it down to the `Input` component (which is a child of `Open`) :

```
<Input conn={this.props.conn} />

......

Open.propTypes = {
  conn: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

Finally in `Input` I try to use it :

```
this.props.conn.send(this.state.msg);

......

Input.propTypes = {
  conn: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

And It throws errors...

If I try to require `conn` as a `func` PropType, (as above), it says that an object was provided. And If I require `conn` as an `object` nothing happens. No errors, but `conn`'s `.send` function obviously isn't being called.

Next I tried passing down the `.send` function as the prop instead :

```
<Open
   conn={this.conn.send}
/>
```

But throws an `Illegal invocation` error!

So how do you pass a websocket connection down to child components in React?

Comment: Wow! Proof that asking a question on SO sometimes results in you seeing the error you've made yourself! Of course I wasn't seeing anything in the console from the Input .send as I wasn't echoing it anywhere!! OpenSocket (where it is being echo'd) is only called on ComponentDidMount in the Main component. Doh! So it is working as expected. Apologies!

Comment: if you resolved your issue, please post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple and I felt a bit silly after I re-read my question when the answer jumped out at me.

Basically everything does work as expected, and just for the record the `Proptype` most certainly is `object`. I just wasn't reading the response I was sending back to the client anywhere in my front end code. `onmessage` was the missing link. In my case I was trying to detect if a client was typing in the input box, this would update the state of the component and pass that down to the relevant child components. I'm also using a `setTimeout` here to clear the state after 3 seconds.
Also don't forget to `JSON.parse` the response from the websocket.

```
this.conn.onmessage = e => {
  if (e.data) {
    let data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    if (data.action === 'typing') {
      this.setState({
        isTyping: data.msg
      });
      setTimeout(this.clearIsTyping, 3000);
    }
  }
};

clearIsTyping = () => {
  this.setState({
    isTyping: ''
  });
};
```

Comment: I am getting this error: "DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': WebSocket object could not be cloned."

Can you help?